# Is this move constructor unnecessary

Tags: c++, c++11

In the following code:

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base(const SomeClass& c) : m_c(c) {}
    SomeClass m_c;
};

class Derived : Base
{
public:
    Derived(const SomeClass& c) : Base(c) {}
    Derived(SomeClass&& c) : Base(static_cast<Base&&>(c)) {} // Unnecessary?
}
```

Is the move constructor above unnecessary? I can't think of a scenario where it would give any advantage against the lvalue reference one?

Comment: Well, of course it's unnecessary when the classes are otherwise empty... in fact, why even have a copy constructor?

Comment: Both classes are actually that empty?  ... why have any constructors at all?

Comment: @Yakk Sorry, thought the interface was enough to illustrate the problem. Added a representative implementation

Comment: This is actually not a move constructor, but just a normal constructor, that takes an rvalue as a parameter. In any way, ttat code is just stupid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, that code is strange.  And broken.

`static_cast<Base&&>(c)` creates a temporary `Base` object.  It then passes that temporary base object in a context where elision is blocked to the `Base` object that is the base of `Derived`.

This causes the passed `SomeClass&& c` to be first copied, *then moved* into the `Base` of `Derived`.  If `SomeClass` lacks move constructors, this causes *2* copies in that case.

I cannot think of a reason you'd want to do that.  However, in some code bases, the side effects I have listed above could have observable consequences.

A more conventional way to move construct from a `SomeClass` is `Derived( SomeClass&& c ):Base(std::move(c)) {}` and add `Base( SomeClass&& c ):m_c(std::move(c)) {}` to `Base`.  That moves `SomeClass` smoothly into the base's `m_c` instead of the gymnastics above.

Comment: I'm looking at a piece of code that I didn't write myself, and this was exactly my conclusion as well. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: @AndreasBrinck There is a possibility that the `const&` and `&&` ctors would do something different in the actual code base: that is the problem with posting translations of code whose purpose you don't understand, naturally.

Comment: @AndreasBrinck I spotted something I missed.  In the real code, is there a move constructor for either `SomeClass` or `Base`?  Are there side effects to copy/move?  Are there pointers-to-itself inside either?

Comment: No, there is no move constructor for `SomeClass` or `Base`. The code above is not exactly the same as what I'm looking at but is sufficient to illustrate the problem, it doesn't do anything esoteric, `Base`/`SomeClass` both look like pre C++11 code.

Comment: @AndreasBrinck so I re-edited my answer.  Almost completely -- `static_cast<Base&&>` I originally misread as `static_cast<SomeClass&&>`.  The effects of `static_cast<Base&&>` is quite strange...  Note that outside of MSVC2013, C++11 compilers will generate move constructors if you don't stop them (like you do in `Base` above).